# Python with selenium over PhantomJS find_by_xpath error in google search

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, bing

When use code below I have a Error with selenium over PhantomJS find_by_xpath in google search result：

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=test')
t = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[8]/div/h3/a").text
print(t)
driver.quit()
```

Error:
https://36.media.tumblr.com/df9020dcb2a68b969bc8097ceccc187e/tumblr_nkqcdokxnu1r68ev5o1_540.png

in bing

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
#driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=test')
driver.get('http://global.bing.com/search?q=test')
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[8]/div/h3/a").click()
t = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[3]/h2/a").text
print(t)
driver.quit()
```

It's all Right.

xpath1:"**//li[8]/div/h3/a**" and "**//li[3]/h2/a**" are both Right in Xpath.

any idea about google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use some wait , might be possible element is not available when you are trying to access it. I tried this its working fine and giving this as output:
XFINITY Speed Test

Comment: thanks ,it is my netissue , maybe [gfw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall) or others , because it really unavailable .